# Relation between two entities

Tags: symfony, entity, bundle, relation

I search how i can do relation many to one on 2 entity different.

Look my exemple for understand.

[image]

Comment: So you want to link an `Article` with a `Video` by a `Comment` which will have specific properties?

Answer (score 1):

As per the diagram,

One article can have many comments and one video can have many comments.
So, the comment entity have many to one relation with video entity and article entity.

If you are doctrine and yaml metadata files for entities, define the relations in the yaml file for Comments as given below

```
manyToOne:
    article:
      targetEntity: Path\to\ArtcleBunlde\Entity\Article
      joinColumn:
         name: article
         referencedColumnName: id
    video:
      targetEntity: Path\to\VideoBundle\Entity\Video
      joinColumn:
         name: video
         referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: I think you should replace `User` by `Video`.